# Malfunctioning perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I am a newbie to machine learning and have been experimenting with basic perceptrons before moving on to multilayer networks.

The problem I have is with the code below. I have a training data generator which uses a set of weights to generate a truth table.

The problem I have is the perceptron is able to solve/determine the set of weights when the training data was generated with set 'A' but not with set 'B'. When
given training data that was generated with set 'B', it continues in an infinite
loop trying to determine the weights (is this a local minimum issue?)

I do not understand exactly why this is happening. Any help or advice is 
appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
// Calling function 
public static void TestPerceptron ()
    {
        // Problem: 
        // When training data is generated using the 'A' set of weights, the perceptron is able to determine the correct weights based on the given training data.
        // When training data is generated using the 'B' set of weights, the perceptron never completes training and is stuck in an infinite loop

        double[] weights = new double[] {
            //3,2,2,3 // A
            3,2,1,3,1 // B
        };

        double bias = 0.0; 

        var trainingData = PerceptronHelper.GenerateDataSetUsingWeights (weights, bias);
        var perceptron = new Perceptron ();
        perceptron.Train (trainingData, null, null);

        //perceptron.Train (trainingData, weights, bias); 
    }


public class Perceptron
{
    private static Random r = new Random ();
    protected double _bias = r.NextDouble();
    protected double[] _weights;

    protected virtual double ComputeOutput(double[] weights, double[] inputs, double bias)
    {
        var total = 0.0;

        for (var index = 0; index < inputs.Length-1; index++) 
        {
            total += weights [index] * inputs [index];
        }

        return total + (1 * bias);
    }

    protected virtual void SetWeights(ref double[] weights, double[] inputs, double error, double learningRate, ref double bias)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < inputs.Length-1; index++) 
        {
            weights[index] = weights [index] + (learningRate * error * inputs [index]);
        }

        bias += learningRate * error * 1;
    }

    public virtual void Train(double[][] trainingData, double[] idealWeights, double? idealBias)
    {
        var learningRate = 1.0;
        var totalError = 1.0;
        var targetError = 0.0;
        var epochs = 0.0;
        var bias = _bias;
        var weights = new double[trainingData[0].Length-1];

        if (idealBias.HasValue)
            bias = idealBias.Value;

        if (idealWeights != null)
            weights = idealWeights;

        while (totalError > targetError) 
        {
            totalError = 0.0;

            for (var index = 0; index < trainingData.Length; index++) 
            {
                var inputs = trainingData [index];

                // get target
                var target = inputs [inputs.Length - 1];

                // compute output
                var computed = ComputeOutput (weights, inputs, bias);

                // pass computed through activation
                var output = PerceptronHelper.Activation (computed);

                // determine error 
                var error = (target - output);

                // adjust weights
                SetWeights (ref weights, inputs, error, learningRate, ref bias);

                totalError += Math.Abs(error);

                var weightsMsg = "Weights: ";

                foreach(var weight in weights)
                {
                    weightsMsg += weight + "|";
                }

                Console.WriteLine (String.Format ("error: {0} weights: {1} bias: {2}", totalError, weightsMsg, bias));
            }

            epochs++;
        }

        _bias = bias;
        _weights = weights;
    }

    public void Predict(double[] inputs)
    {
        var sum = 0.0;

        for (var index = 0; index < inputs.Length; index++) 
        {
            sum += inputs [index] * _weights [index] + 1 * _bias;

            Console.WriteLine (String.Format("input: {0} weight: {1} bias: {2}", inputs[index], _weights[index], _bias));
        }

        var output = PerceptronHelper.Activation (sum);
        Console.WriteLine ("Output:{0}", output);
    }
}


public static class PerceptronHelper
{
    // generate training data based on given weights - the number of inputs = number of weights 
    public static double[][] GenerateDataSetUsingWeights(double[] idealWeights, double bias)
    {
        var weights = idealWeights;
        var inputs = new double[weights.Length];
        var numInputCombinations = Math.Pow(2,inputs.Length); 
        var trainData = new double[(int)numInputCombinations][];
        int inputValue = 0;

        // generate training data
        for (var index = 0; index < numInputCombinations; index++) 
        {
            var sum = 0.0;  

            // last item in array is expected output
            var trainDataLine = new double[weights.Length+1];

            var binary = Convert.ToString (inputValue, 2);
            binary = binary.PadLeft (weights.Length, '0');

            // create training data line
            for (var wIndex = 0; wIndex < weights.Length; wIndex++) 
            {
                inputs [wIndex] = double.Parse(binary[wIndex].ToString());
                trainDataLine [wIndex] = inputs [wIndex];
                sum += inputs [wIndex] * weights [wIndex];
            }

            sum += (1 * bias);

            var output = Activation (sum);

            // store the expected result in the last item of the array
            trainDataLine [weights.Length] = output;

            // add the line to the data
            trainData[index] = trainDataLine;

            inputValue++;
        }

        return trainData;
    }

    public static double Activation (double sum) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine (String.Format("evaluating :{0}", sum));
        return Math.Abs(sum) >= 5 ? 1 : 0;

    }
}
```

A sample of the output:

[https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8a0ad995f81066db!176&authkey=!AGgY8Iy4g_8lpv4&ithint=file%2crtf](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8a0ad995f81066db!176&authkey=!AGgY8Iy4g_8lpv4&ithint=file%2Crtf)

Comment: Can you debug and examine exactly what is happening with the weights in B. What value to the have (is it close to the correct value) and why is the stopping condition never triggered?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated the post with a sample of the output. Looking at the output the problem seems to be the total error that causes the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the learning rate to 0.075 fixed the issue.